# How to make "\n" a new line in terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, linux

I'm trying to view the HHVM log in a friendly way - currently it just comes out as a giant block of text.

I've noticed there are various instances of "\n" in there. How can I get my terminal (gnome terminal, over SSH) to display them as new lines, or replace them with something that does make it a new line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sed for this:

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' < log_file|less
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use `tail -f`?

Comment: Here it is: `tail -f log_file | sed 's/\\n/\n/'`

Comment: It might be better to use `sed 's/\\n/\n/g'` because depending on the exact output there may be more than one "\n" on the same line.